# Scheduled portlet redeployment

Tags: java, liferay, portlet

I've got  non-instanceable portlet on liferay portal 6.1.20-ee-ga2. After startup I cache some data from DB for better performance. I know, that data may be updated once a day, at 23 PM. How can I easily update data in cache? 
Is it possible to reinit portlet automatically, every day after 23 PM, or should I wrote updating cache manually? (With scheduler or something like that)

Comment: Scheduler is your friend :)

Comment: How long does it take to update the data? Can you live with a single request per day to take 2 seconds because the cache is updated? Or does it take 5 minutes?

Comment: Can you change the portlet code or is it not changeable?